# CSS transition plus jQuery css method inconsistent between Safari and Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, css-transitions

This is a really weird issue! If any brains out their could explain I would appreciate it!

I am trying to get a CSS transition to run when a page loads using the following code ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/cineyoko/1/))

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-message">My message</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#my-message {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}

.my-transition {
    transition: height 4s;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    var $myMessage = $( '#my-message' );

    var height = $myMessage.height();

    $myMessage.height( 0 );

    $myMessage.addClass( 'my-transition' );

    $myMessage.css( 'height', height );

} );
```

The transition works as expected in Safari however in Chrome it just shows instantly (no transition).

The weird thing is if you change the last command in the JavaScript from `$myMessage.css( 'height', height );` to `$myMessage.heigh( height );` it works in both!

WHY!?!?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the behaviour of chrome, I added the setTimeout on your js and it worked

```
setTimeout(function(){  $myMessage.css( 'height', height );},1);
```

[Updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cineyoko/4/)